# Which font is used for the Yorkhill Children's Charity logo?

Tags: font-identification

Can anyone tell me the name of this font? Or similar fonts?

[image: Yorkhill Children's Charity logo]

Comment: Please review our Font Identification guidelines and edit the question so that others may benefit from it in the future: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/guidelines-for-font-identification-questions

Answer (score 7):

Usually the best solution is to ask the client, even if they aren't the client you can still always ask. (As long as you aren't going to do something similar, always be original!)

In this case they've used it or a similar typeface on their site. If you inspect the headings (right click) you'll see they've used  "[FS Lola](http://www.fontsmith.com/fonts/fs-lola.cfm) Web Bold Italic" and "Aller". These might not be the same as the logo but are close/complimentary.

[image]

Comment: another trick is to dig into a site for any PDF versions of their publications and check for font embedding. If they have well-branded publications, they are bound to have the proper typeface embedded.

Comment: Good point, however with logos I usually find they've expanded it to shapes so it's an eps. Will definitely be using this in the future though rather than what the font

Answer (score 0):

C3Lawrence is right...It looks like they have used 
FS Lola Web Bold Italic. [image]

And something similar is the font 'Appetite Italic" which is free.[image]

Comment: Sorry, not even close in my perception.